# Syntax to use where and groupby together in active record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, group-by

I tried googling but didnt find an example that uses where and groupby together

Trying to apply a where and then group:

```
User.group(:role_id).where('created_at >= ?', start_date)

User.where('created_at >= ?', start_date).group(:role_id)
```

I get the error :

```
ERROR:  column "user.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I might just use raw sql but there has to be a cleaner documented way ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to append at least a `select()` condition to the query since the group_by condition works together with a `count(*)`, `sum(*)`, `distinct(*)` or other SQL aggregate function. The fields that appear in the `select()` conditions must be those expressed in the `group_by` conditions or aggregate functions.

Eg.

```
User.group(:role_id).where('created_at >= ?', start_date).select('count(*) as count, role_id')
```